# Unable to instal subclipse in IMB RTC

Tags: subclipse, rtc

I am trying to install subclipse in IBM RTC RTC-Client-Mac-4.0 via this this url
http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.10.x

Through 
Help > Install New Software > Add

I get

Your original request has been modified.
  "SVNKit Library" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Subclipse Integration for Mylyn 3.x (Optional) 3.0.0 (org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.mylyn.feature.group 3.0.0)
  Missing requirement: Subclipse Integration for Mylyn 3.x (Optional) 3.0.0 (org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.mylyn.feature.group 3.0.0) requires 'org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core [3.0.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found

When I look for software updates via Help> check for updates ....I get no updates found. When I look for installed softwares I dont see subclipse as listed either.

[image]

[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have Mylyn installed, which seems to be the case, then just deselect the option to install the Subclipse Mylyn integration.

Comment: Hi Mark, I ended up using this http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.0.x Instead and that seemed to work.